# In flutter_treeview how to change the color of selected node

Tags: flutter, treeview

In Flutter [flutter_treeview package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_treeview)

How we change the color of selected node

or
(selected node background color)

Thankyou

Comment: I am having the same problem, have you figured it out?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem as the author, and I found some working solution on my own, but I don't think that its the most correct one. But I will use it as a work around for now.

The idea is to define the `colorScheme:` attribute of `TreeViewTheme` under `theme:` attribute, and setting the `primary` field.

```dart
return TreeView(
  theme: TreeViewTheme(
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
      primary: Colors.grey, # put whatever color in here.
    ),
  )
)
```

hopefully someone have a better answer, because I Imagine this will fail while app is in dark mode for example.